# Libgdx | Scene2d | How to use actions on an animation

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

How would I go about using actions (eg...fade in/fade out) on an animation? Would I have to set the fade in/out on each individual texture in the animation at once?

Answer (score 0):

Add the animation to an Actor and add the action on it.

```
public class AnimationWithAction extends Actor {
    Animation animation = new Animation(5, textures);
}

AnimationWithAction anim = new AnimationWithAction();
anim.addAction(youraction);
```